# 'jhsdb' command not found in image taken from azul/zulu-openjdk-debian:14

Tags: java-14, azul-zulu

I upgraded an application to Java 14 through Docker using the image azul/zulu-openjdk-debian:14. However, I am not able to obtain heap statistics as the container does not have jhsdb (jmap) installed. would like to know which package to install to be able to get heap statistics, run GC and take thread dumps.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've pulled the latest version:

```
# docker pull azul/zulu-openjdk-debian:14
# docker run -it  azul/zulu-openjdk-debian:14 jmap -?
Usage:
jmap -clstats <pid>
    to connect to running process and print class loader statistics
...
```

Comment: The author asked about jhsdb specifically. Is it available in the Azul JDKs?